# Highlighting chrome tabs, i.e , changing either the colour or width of the tab so as to segregate it from others

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am building an extension where I need to highlight a particular tab. Let's say I have the tab id. After going through developer.chrome.com I am unable to find a way to color the tab. Then on trying to update the width of the tab, I get the following error:
Code: chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {width: 3000});

Error in event handler for browserAction.onClicked: Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property 'width': Unexpected property.
    at chrome-extension://paljhphpjpoanajlejoemeodabbmcncc/background.js:20:14

I want to find a way to segregate the tab which I want to update, from all the other tabs so that I can locate that tab. Is there any way to do this, any modification of css, etc. ?

Comment: The error message shouldn’t come as a surprise, since `width` is not listed under the properties that you _can_ update, here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update There is however a `highlighted` property – see if that maybe fits your needs.

Comment: try using the pin property. ex:chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {pin:true});

Answer (score 0):

You cannot affect appearance of tabs in Chrome. This ain't Firefox.

`highlighted` is for selecting several tabs (to move or close them together). That minimally changes the appearance and has unwanted side effects. It will also be gone on any click on tab strip.

`pinned` is a specific operation that, again, has a lot of side effects.

So, no. You can't. You could consider modifying the favicon (needs to be done with a content script, so you'll need very broad permissions).

Comment: So no other way to mark a tab, so that I can segregate it from others, other than changing the icon ? But there are extensions which change a tabs look. How do they go about changing it. Any css, or any other way. Thanks.

Comment: No, there are no extensions that change tabs' look for Chrome*. Unless you can point to an example. (*: Except Themes, but they can't select which tabs to change)

Comment: Could you suggest any example as to how to go about changing the favicon for a tab ?

Comment: You'll need to inject a content script, like I said. After that, it's the same as if you're changing a page's own icon.